# What mass of fragrances does a cubic meter of air contain on average?

Tags: aromatic-compounds, atmospheric-chemistry

What mass of fragrance are airborne in scented environments for example in a perfume deparment?

What is the minimum g/m3 of fragrance that a human can detect, and how much is present when it evaporates from an oven, in a cookie shop, from a cut lawn, near a perfumed lady and average levels from a day of walking.

What range of fragrance concentrations do humans typically have to cope with.

Comment: Unless I misunderstood you in the first,  you might want to talk about (mostly terpenoid) **fragrances** rather than about (the structure class) of aromatic compounds in order to avoid further misunderstandings.

Comment: Okay, perhaps the question is too difficult because some fragrances can be detected in volumes 1000 times greater than others. it's possible to evaporate scents and weigh them, to know the quantities that represent different levels. in general the weight of fragrance of an essential oil for a cubic meter is less than a microgram. i figure that's in the range of 1ppm.

Comment: This question will be incredibly difficult to answer. The first part requires a lot of of information about the given environment, and any analytical chemist will tell you that there is no general answer that can be given. it will vary from department to department, as well as on what perfumes they carry, how often they're sprayed, and a ton of other factors. The second question, the first part might have an answer if a study was done, but definitely varies person to person. The second part of question 2, again has many circumstantial variables. Third, is answerable if there's been a study.